# Passing parameter from a .JSP to another .JSP

Tags: jsp

Gretings 
This is for a project for my university. The idea is to offer a functionality where we can delete an employee using .JSP.

I tried to implement this using two .jsp's as well as a little bit of clientside Javascript

The first jsp is the actual display of the data, on this jsp I have a dynamic generated table as a result from a query. Here is the creation of the table as well as the select. :

```
        <%
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=HR;user=sa;password=sa;");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sqlStr = "SELECT EmpID, EmpFirstName, EmpLastName, EmpJobTitle, EmpSalary FROM Employees order by EmpID";
        ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(sqlStr);
        %>
        <table id ="tabEmployees" border=1>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Job Title</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
            <% while (rset.next()) { %>
            <tr>
                <td><%=rset.getInt("EmpID")%></td>
                <td><%=rset.getString("EmpFirstName")%></td>
                <td><%=rset.getString("EmpLastName")%></td>
                <td><%=rset.getString("EmpJobTitle")%></td>
                <td><%=rset.getDouble("EmpSalary")%></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Delete"  onclick="deleteRow(this)"> </td>
            </tr>                
        <% } %>
        </table>
```

As you can observe I have a delete button on each row which its purpose is to delete that row (obviously) . This delete button has behind a javascript function (deleteRow). The code of javascript is on a .javascript file. Here it is :

```
 function deleteRow(r)
     {
        var confirmation = confirm("Delete the row ?");
        if (confirmation == true) 
        {    
            var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex; 
            var tabEmployee = document.getElementById("tabEmployees");
            var cellID = tabEmployee.rows[i].cells[0];
            var empID = cellID.firstChild.data;
            window.alert("1)The Emp id is = "+ empID);
            var hidElement = document.getElementById("hidInput");
            hidElement.value = empID;

            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
            {
                if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) 
                {
                    document.getElementById("showDeleteResult").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
                }
            };
            window.alert("2)The Emp id is = "+ empID);
            xhttp.open("get", "deleteEmployees.jsp", true);
            xhttp.send();
            document.getElementById("tabEmployees").deleteRow(i);

        } 
    }
```

And finally I have the actual deletion of data on another jsp named deleteEmployees.jsp which has the following code :

```
   <body>
        <%@ page import = "java.sql.*" %>

        <%Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

        String empID = request.getParameter("empID");
        SQLException ex1=null;
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        out.println("Employee ID " + empID);
        try 
            {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=HR;user=sa;password=sa;");
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String delEmployee = "delete from dbo.Employees "
                                + "where empID = " + empID;
            stmt.executeUpdate (delEmployee);
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
            }
        catch(SQLException ex)
            {
                ex1=ex;
            }
        if (ex1==null)
            {
                out.println("Employee Deleted");
            }
            else
            {
               out.println("Problem during the deletion of the employee ");  
            }

        %>
    </body>
```

While the EmpID while on the first page has a legitimate value when it reaches the deleteEmployees.jsp is null. How this empID can retain its value ?

Any constructive answer is welcomed

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the empID to the other jsp as a request parameter:

```
xhttp.open("get", "deleteEmployees.jsp?empID=" + empID, true);
```

Comment: If it answered your question can you mark it as the selected answer please